# AspNetBoilerplate Returning all records depite where clause

Tags: linq, aspnetboilerplate, abp

Im having a problem with the a LINQ query using aspnetboilerplate. despite a where clause its return all records.

I want to select all records that have an EnrolResponse.IsComplete = true.

i have three entities

```
public class User : Entity<int>, IFullAudited
{
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public List<EnrollAttemptRequest> EnrollAttempts { get; set; }

}

public class EnrollAttemptRequest : Entity<int>
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public EnrollAttemptResponse EnrolResponse { get; set; }

}

public class EnrollAttemptResponse : Entity<int>, IFullAudited
{
    public int EnrollAttemptRequestId { get; set; }

    public bool IsComplete { get; set; }

}
```

the following query is returning all records, even if the IsComplete is equal to false.

```
        var enroledUsers = await _userRepository.GetAll()
            .Where(x => x.EnrollAttempts.Any(y=>y.EnrolResponse.IsComplete == true))
            .Include(x=>x.EnrollAttempts)
            .ThenInclude(x=>x.EnrolResponse)
            .ToListAsync();
```

If breaking the query down to an IQueryable but i get the same result

Comment: Create a repro project on GitHub that is forked from [aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template).

Comment: I agree with the answer given below.  The where clause just needs a min of 1 record to be meet the criteria - and I don't think that was intended by OP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you need All() instead of Any()?

If you use Any() you get all records if at least 1 satisfies the condition.
If you use All() you get all records if all satisfy the condition

```
var enroledUsers = await _userRepository.GetAll()
            .Where(x => x.EnrollAttempts.All(y=>y.EnrolResponse.IsComplete == true))
            .Include(x=>x.EnrollAttempts)
            .ThenInclude(x=>x.EnrolResponse)
            .ToListAsync();
```